# PHP how to count total number of times being added to cart ( in_array() )

Tags: php

all_product.php -> list out all the products

cart.php->show items being added to cart.

Every time I click add to cart, it will be added to array and i list out all of them. The result will be something like the following **(before using in_array()  )**

```
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 4
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 7
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 6
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 5
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 5
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 6
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 4
```

I use in_array() function to add items to cart only if it exists. So the result will become like the following instead :

```
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 4
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 7
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 6
Products that are added to cart, ID -> 5
```

So my question is how to count the total number of times being added for each product; Basically just like each product's quantity.

**all_products.php**

```
require 'config.php';
$q = mysqli_query( $db->conn(), "SELECT * FROM product" );

if( mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 ) { // Check if there are results
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
echo '<p> '.$row['product_name'].' | <a href="cart.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Add To Cart!</a></p>';
}           
}
```

**cart.php**

```
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['id'])){

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart']=[]; //Create session 1st time

}   
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

    if(!in_array($_GET['id'],$_SESSION['cart'])){ //add item only if doesn't exist
        $_SESSION['cart'][]=$_GET['id'];
    }
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $x => $item_added) { // all products being added to cart
    echo "Products that are added to cart, ID -> " . $item_added;
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
}else{ // if user view this page directly without "?id=" , show error
echo "I hate php!";
}
```

Comment: `count($_SESSION['cart'])` no?

Comment: @ineersa : nope he wants quantity for each product

Comment: @ineersa  no, this function is to count how may items in an array.  I am doing a add to cart function. I want to check each individual product's total number of times being clicked -> Add to cart.

Comment: I'd change my array structure. Something like `$_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']] = array('count' => 2, 'somethingelse' => 'test');`

Comment: Try using twodimensional arrays or sth like that and increase a counter if the element already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving product id as a value save it as a key of an array and increment the counter each time someone adds the product in cart.

So your code will look something like this,

```
if(!array_key_exists($_GET['id'],$_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]=1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]++;
}
```

Using this method both of your purpose would be solved, only unique products will be added in cart and with their quantity.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

> **array_key_exists()** checks if the given key or index exists in the array.

---

To retrieve the products with their quantity run a `foreach` loop like this,

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $productid=>$quantity) {
   echo $productid." added ".$quantity." times <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a key value pair:

```
$cart=["name" => 1, "name2" => 2]
```

To add a new value do:

```
$cart[$name]=1;
```

To increase:

```
$cart[$name]++;
```